# PHP if is True return false

Tags: php, boolean

I'm trying to post a an output changes based on whether the variable is true, but nothing shows up after I have inserted an if statement inside the foreach loop.  What am I missing?

```
$odd = TRUE;

        foreach ( $recent as $item ) {

            if ( $odd == TRUE ) {
                $out .= '<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">';
                $out .= '<a href="' . get_permalink( $item['ID'] ) . '">';
                $out .= get_the_post_thumbnail( $item['ID'] ); 
                $out .= '</a>';
                $out .= '</div><div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">';
                $out .=  get_the_excerpt( $item['ID'] );
                $out .= '</div>';
                return FALSE;
            } else {
                $out .= '<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">';
                $out .=  get_the_excerpt( $item['ID'] );
                $out .= '</a>';
                $out .= '</div><div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">';
                $out .= '<a href="' . get_permalink( $item['ID'] ) . '">';
                $out .= get_the_post_thumbnail( $item['ID'] ); 
                $out .= '</div>';
                return TRUE;
            }
        }
```

Comment: you know what `return` does, right?

Comment: Where are you printing the `$out` variable?

Comment: remove return and use echo exit statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code , instead of returning $odd , change the value and echo $out so you will achieve what you need .

```
$odd = TRUE;
$out = '';

foreach ( $recent as $item ) {

    if ( $odd == TRUE ) {
        $out .= '<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">';
        $out .= '<a href="' . get_permalink( $item['ID'] ) . '">';
        $out .= get_the_post_thumbnail( $item['ID'] ); 
        $out .= '</a>';
        $out .= '</div><div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">';
        $out .=  get_the_excerpt( $item['ID'] );
        $out .= '</div>';
        $odd = FALSE;
    } else {
        $out .= '<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">';
        $out .=  get_the_excerpt( $item['ID'] );
        $out .= '</a>';
        $out .= '</div><div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">';
        $out .= '<a href="' . get_permalink( $item['ID'] ) . '">';
        $out .= get_the_post_thumbnail( $item['ID'] ); 
        $out .= '</div>';
        $odd = TRUE;
    }
}

echo $out;
```